# PHP: How do I get the middle of my $_GET variable?

Tags: php, jquery, string, variables, get

I have a `$_GET` variable that is a combination of `md5('currentdate')` + `ID` + another encrypted random string. Hopefully with this, I can secure my URL somehow.

Example URL:

```
create_pdf.php?goto=qredit&qrid=1e02b73e2b1cb88685499f38508cf6e84317e62166fc8586dfa4d1bc0e1742c08b
                                                                ^^
```

I need to get the middle of the `$_GET['qrid']` variable, which in this case is `43`.
I tried using `substr()` but I don't get my desired result.

**UPDATE:**
Here's how I yield my `$_GET` variable.

```
<a href="create_pdf.php?goto=qredit&qrid=<?php echo md5($today).$_GET['qrid'].md5($_GET['qrid']); ?>" target="_blank" id="upload_button">-random whatnot-</a>
```

Comment: * is not part of the string. I was trying to make it bold so you can see where it is.

Comment: I'm new in SO. I apologize for my mistake.

Comment: is the length of the second encrypted string fixed or not? If it does, you might have to use if-else to find the middle part.

Comment: using md5 will always yield 32 characters AFAIK.

Comment: yes, so you use md5 for it as well. i see

Comment: You might also look at `mt_rand` in place of your md5 - if I take it correctly that you're just looking for a random string. The md5 of the current date/time would be relatively easy to predict, but an mt_rand would be much harder.

Comment: No. The ID I'm trying to get isn't always 2 characters, so a constant value in the substr() will not solve it.

Comment: You need to provide us the code that produced your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first and second strings are a fixed 32 characters, try this to retrieve the ID value from the string:

```
// Get all characters up to the last 32 chracters, starting at 32nd character
$id = substr($_GET['qrid'], 32, strlen($_GET['qrid'])-64);
```

Comment: This was my first solution too. However, the ID is not always 2 characters. It might be more in the future.

Comment: @user3277936 Is the "another encrypted random string" a fixed length? If so, how many characters?

Comment: It's md5 as well. So it's 32.

Comment: Hey, it worked. Care to explain what happened in your code? Thanks!

Comment: @user3277936: Care to look up the functions in the manual and find that out by yourself …?

Comment: No, I meant, why was the last argument strlen($_GET['qrid']) - 64 ?

Comment: 2 md5 functions yield a 64 characters string. Thus the original qrid string length is _strlen($_GET['qrid']) - 64_.

Answer (score 0):

Can use regex for cleaner solution. The front and end strings are always 32 assuming it's MD5. The middle capture group would get your id starting from 0.

```
preg_match('/\d{32}(\w+)\d{32}/', $_GET['qrid'], $matches);
$id = $matches[1];
```

Comment: You know what they say, "if you try to solve a problem using regex, you have two problems." Cheers. :)

Comment: yep shouldn't overuse it, i think it's handy for lightweight stuffs though